# I'm having var char error when trying to do division operation on sql

Tags: mysql, variables, ssms

The code is

```
Select location,date, total_cases,total_deaths, 
        (total_cases/total_death)*100 as death percentage
```

Both total_cases and total_death contain varchar
How do I cast or convert them

Comment: Did you look at the [MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html) Oddly there is a `CAST()` function in there

Comment: But the obvious question would have to be, why did you place a number in a VARCHAR() datatype? I would suggest you change that and kill 2 birds with one stone

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem like this :

```
Select location,date, total_cases,total_deaths, 
        (CAST(total_cases as SIGNED)/CAST(total_deaths as SIGNED))*100 as death_percentage
        from tab ;
```

it is more practical to modify the types of the two columns like this :

```
ALter  table tab modify total_cases integer ;
ALter  table tab modify total_deaths integer ;
```